# to make navigation drawer on status bar?

Tags: android

I am working on Android project and I am implementing the Navigation Drawer. I am reading through the new Material Design Spec and the Material Design Checklist.
But I cann't solve my problem.
Please anyone help me?Look Screenshot.
Below is a screenshot of my navigation drawer is not cover on status bar

[image]

I want to be like that screenshot.Navigation Drawer is over on status bar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps: 
  put a new theme in your styles:

**values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">  
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**values/styles.xml(v21)**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Specify that your Activity now uses this theme, like so

```
<activity  
    android:name="MyDrawerNavActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

That's it.

Comment: cann't solve @Pushpendra Choudhary.My statusBarColor is #FFFFFF.I don't want to transparent.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <!-- Main layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
<!-- Nav drawer -->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.DrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
```

values/themes.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
<!--This makes the status bar transparent in KK and Lollipop-->
<!--You do not need values-v21 and if you create them make sure you extend from this one-->
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Comment: Cann't solve @Rahul Karande.Nav drawer is under status bar as transparent.I want to navdrawer is overlay on status bar .Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Follow this steps:
in studio

1)file
 2)new 
3)Actvity
4)NavigationDrawer
and go to next and user ur code in this

I hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks @Rahul Karande.This is normal Nav Drawer.Please look my question.Thanks.